# Create a batch to launch more than one batch

Tags: batch-file, minecraft

I'm trying to make a batch file to launch one of the 2 batch files I've made from 1 .batch file instead of 2 separate. I'm trying to make it where you can enter a number or letter, click enter, and it would launch that .batch. I've already tested the 2 seperate .batch files to be working: I'm just trying to find a .batch file to launch them from 1 place, so I wouldn't have to keep going go through folders just to launch them. Why I need this: The 2 seperate .batch files were made after I downloaded minecraft portable 2.7.2 from minecraftforum twice that used jportable (32 bit + 64 bit program). I didn't want to keep switching between folders every time I plugged in my USB if the computer had a different bit from the last, so I wanted to find a .batch to launch one one of the 2 .batch files (instead of me constantly switching, I would simply go to this batch, select one of the 2, and the selected would launch)

This batch that I'm looking for would basically act like a launch panel for the 2 .batch files I made. The 2 .batch files I made are:

```batch
set zone=mcp_data
set APPDATA=%CD%\%zone%
Start MC64.exe
exit
```

2nd is:

```batch
set zone=mcp_data
set APPDATA=%CD%\%zone%
Start MC32.exe
exit
```

If anyone can help, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

This should work instead of having two batch files:

```
set zone=mcp_data
set APPDATA=%CD%\%zone%
if defined ProgramFiles(x86) (
     Start MC64.exe
  ) else (
     start mc32.exe
  )
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

Two possible solutions, the first example solution accepts a parameter, so in your command line type 'launcher 1' or 'launcher 2'. This has an added advantage that you can setup shortcuts with the appropriate parameters.  The second solution does what you actually asked for which is a prompt.  I have combined both into one batch file so you can use both approaches.

```
@echo First solution
if "%1"=="1" call Batch1.bat
if "%1"=="2" call Batch2.bat
if not "%1"=="" goto end
rem or alternatively

@echo Second solution
set /p id=Enter number: 
if "%id%"=="1" call Batch1.bat
if "%id%"=="2" call Batch1.bat
:end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%=AMD64 (
 start MC64.EXE
) else (
 start MC32.EXE
)
```

Why more complex?